# datatables filter on table data not making any changes to the rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to filter a datatable based on a column date with no success, even though the I get the data filtered like I want, but the UI of the table is not changing, what am I missing here?
I have this code:

```
  var filterTable = hpDataTable.
                    column(1).
                    data().
                    filter(function (value, index, api) {

                    var today = new Date();
                    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    var dateFromColumn = moment(value).toDate();
                    return dateFromColumn < today ? false : true;

                 //there is no affect on the table ui.
                }).draw();

                //filterTable returns the data I want.
                console.log(filterTable);
            }
```

Comment: can you put your code js fiddle So that it will essay to debug? or show code here also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()):

> This method should not be confused with [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) which is used to search for records in the DataTable - i.e. the [`filter()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) method does not change the rows that are displayed in the DataTable.

You need to implement [custom filtering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) instead.

For example:

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// Apply search criteria
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
       var dateFromColumn = moment(data[1]).toDate();
       return dateFromColumn < today ? false : true;
    }
);

// Redraw table
hpDataTable.draw();

// Retrieve data
var data = hpDataTable.column(1, { search: 'applied' }).data();

// Restore search criteria
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

Comment: @OffirPe'er, In DataTable's terms filtering only returns you the data but doesn't change UI, searching does change UI and you can retrieve the data using [selector modifiers](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier).